# Calling a panel's add method from a child widget

Tags: java, gwt

I have created a Composite widget comprising of a TextBox and a Button. What I am trying to implement here is that another instance of this widget be added to its parent vertical panel on entering text in the TextBox of widget. To achieve that I've tried following:

```
public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event){
    if(event.getSource() == optionBox && optionCount>=2){
        getParent().add(new OptionWidget(optionCoutn+1));
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error:That "symbol:   method add(Widget)" cannot be found in Widget class.
From which it is obvious that add method from VerticalPanel class is not being called here.

I've added two instances of this widget to VerticalPanel using UiBinder template.

What should I do to call VerticalPanel's add method ?

Comment: Where you have put the above mentioned code snippet ? Composite widget 's class or main view (consisting of Vertical panel and composite widget) ?

Comment: Also check in firebug whether the Composite Widget is added to the DOM or not? Sometimes because of height/width issues, Widget won't be shown in the UI (Hidden).

Comment: It works now after adding it to Composite widget's constructor just before initWidget() invocation. Previously I had added above code as member function and Composite widget's class implemented the KeyPressHandler interface. Now I am adding this KeyPressHandler as an anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the result of `getParent` to `VerticalPanel`

```
VerticalPanel ParentPanel=(VerticalPanel)getParent();
ParentPanel.add(new OptionWidget(optionCoutn+1));
```

Comment: That solved the error but intended functionality is not working. It's not adding new widget to VerticalPanel.